# SQL JOIN limit to top 1 when have multiple column join

Tags: sql

I need to join 2 tables

```
tableA
----------
colA   colB
A      1
B      2
C      3
D      4

tableB
----------
colC  ColD ColE...
A     A    X
A     B    X
A     C    X
B     A    Y
B     B    Y
B     C    Y
```

Previously I would have joined the table as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
ON b.ColC =                  --This column SHOULD NORMALLY be a unique key column
    (SELECT TOP 1 tempB.ColC
     FROM tableB tempB
     WHERE a.ColA = tempB.ColC
     AND ...(other requirements here)
    )
```

But that does not work here as there is no single unique column in this instance.

EDIT:
The required output is a one to one join to obtain the value in columnE of table2 for use elsewhere.

EDIT AGAIN:
Desired output -

```
ColA ColB ColC ColE ColD
A    1    A    X    any value of a,b,c (doesn't matter)
B    2    B    Y    any value of a,b,c
```

Comment: what is the required output for you? why you joined with top 1?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` gives undefined behaviour on most database systems. What database system are you using? And what is your desired result?

Comment: "that does not work here"..please explain.

Comment: Which value of ColumnE if there are multiple matches? The MAX? The MIN? Any value?

Comment: I have expanded the answer. Basically the query as it stands would need to use a NON UNIQUE column, so the join would be one to many, and I can only use one column to compare to the inner query. There must be a way around this.

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 Use `IN` instead of `=` and lose the `TOP 1`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Any value, as there is a relationship between columns C and E, so all values in col C have exactly one matching value in E.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - I have changed the code to hopefully make my problem more clear. If I cannot join on a UNIQUE column, then my join becomes 1 to many. I need to join 1 to 1. Your suggestion of using IN does not change this.

Comment: For the expected output, we were hoping that you'd show something similar to the two tables at the top - I.e. given those 4 and 6 rows of data, respectively, what output rows are you expecting?

Comment: show your desired output

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever updated again :)

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 Maybe unrelated (and you got plenty of answers), but why select more than `DISTINCT ColE` if you don't care about the other values? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` in subquery or `ROW_NUMBER()` (You haven't specified RDBMS, but guessing SQL Server based on TOP 1)

*`Group By` version:*

```
;WITH CTE_Group AS
(
  SELECT colC, MIN(ColE) ColE FROM TableB
  GROUP BY colC
)
SELECT a.ColA, a.ColB, b.ColE 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN CTE_Group b on a.ColA = b.ColC;
```

*`Row_Number()` version:*

```
;WITH CTE_RN AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColC ORDER BY ColD) RN
  FROM TableB
)
SELECT a.ColA, a.ColB, b.ColE 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN CTE_RN b on a.ColA = b.ColC AND b.RN = 1;
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/637c1/6)**

Comment: this worked, but I went with the other answer as it keeps the logic together (this is part of a much larger join). Although I do agree with other commenters that this answer will be correct in a more general situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

SQL doesn't do "doesn't matter"<sup>1</sup>. Assuming you're using a database system that supports the windowing functions, then this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
JOIN (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColC ORDER BY ColD) as rn
      from tableB) b
ON b.ColC = a.ColC and
   b.rn = 1
```

In this instance, I've decided that the row to select is that which sorts earliest by `ColD`.

<sup>1</sup> By which I mean, even if *you* don't care about what to select, you have to give SQL a specification for what you want to select. If you don't actually care, you might choose a condition (such as that suggested by @Martin Smith) that still leaves things ambiguous and give the optimizer some leeway - but you still have to provide *a* specification.

Comment: `PARTITION BY ColC ORDER BY ColC` would effectively mean "doesn't matter" though. On SQL Server the execution plan for this might show an [`ANY` aggregate](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/07/02/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.colA,a.colB,b.ColC,b.ColE,b.ColD
from tableA a
inner join (select ColC,max(ColD) as ColD,max(ColE) ColE 
            from tableB
            group by colC)b
on a.colA=b.colC
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55642/3)**

Comment: Dangerous general form - I know in the OPs case that all `ColE` values are equal for a particular `ColC` - but in the general case, there's no guarantee that two `MAX`s will select values from the same row.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree with you. But i have made this answer specifically meeting OP requirements. **:)** Thanks for your input.

Comment: I put it more as a general warning for anyone else finding this question/answer in 6 months time who doesn't exactly fit the OPs requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I thought it would be only a basic change.